# getting the id of the inserted row

Tags: java, jdbc

I am inserting records into a database table through plain old JDBC(as this is what the set up is in the project I am working on.. not yet migrated to Hibernate).

here is my table structure

```
employee (empid int indentity not null, empName);
```

when I try to insert record through JDBC code

```
insert into employee(empName) values('something')
```

it works and a record gets inserted.
However I need to get the id against the inserted row. I can try executing a separate select query to get the inserted row but might not get the correct inserted record id if 2 employee names are same.

How do I get the inserted record id using JDBC. I am using `preparedStatment.executeUpdate` which returns 0 or 1 based on whether the record is inserted or not.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Database is SQL Server.. checking the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the the Statement [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS), you can use "RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS" like so -

```
stmt.execute("insert into employee(empName) values('something')",
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
  return rs.getLong(1); // for example.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to read the documentation for JDBC's `Statement#getGeneratedKeys()`, which you must call after doing the insert.  This assumes your database supports retrieving generated keys, which not all databases do.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the db:

**Oracle & PostgreSQL**: when you use a sequence, get the value returned

**Mysql**: `mysql_insert_id()`

**SQL Server**: `@@IDENTITY`

**Custom way**: `select max(id) from table`

**Pure java (JDBC Driver supported)**: see `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`
Retrieves any auto-generated keys created as a result of executing this Statement object.